# foreign key relationship in Django REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create an employee object whose attributes include pre-existing foreign key (Department).when i see employee api.. i am getting department id instead of department name..[image].. please help

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
employee_name = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
surname = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
address = models.CharField(max_length  = 50)
qualification = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
contact_num = PhoneNumberField()
department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
def __str__(self):
    return self.employee_name
```

serialize.py

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
""" Serializer to represent the Chain model """
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Chain model """
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233597/how-to-get-all-the-properties-of-objects-using-foreign-key-in-django-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`StringRelatedField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) for the same.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Chain model """
    department = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

> **`StringRelatedField`** may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its **`__unicode__`** or **`__str__`** method.

If you wish to see all details related to that FK, use [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) as below

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer to represent the Chain model """

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```